# Kazoo/Freeswitch bridged call from restricted number, how to set sip privacy off

Tags: sip, privacy, freeswitch, kazoo

Am bridging an inbound leg to an outbound leg and want to display the called id from the inbound leg on the outbound leg.

Restricted -> (123)456-7890 -> (987)765-4321 (callerId Restricted)

When the caller on the inbound leg has restricted their caller id (*67...), kazoo or freeswitch is setting the "privacy=full" sip header on the outbound leg, so that caller id shows up as restricted.

When the caller on the inbound leg does not restrict their caller id, the outbound leg shows the inbound called number as we desire.

(123)555-1212 -> (123)456-7890 -> (987)765-4321 (callerid 1234567890)

FreeSWITCH Version 1.4.26~64bit ( 64bit)
Kazoo V3.0

Added custom_sip_headers.privacy on the device, kazoo sends sip_h_privacy to freeswitch.

Added privacy to Custom_SIP_Headers on the endpoint and kazoo sends ecallmgr_SIP-Privacy=no to freeswitch.

Here is information from the INVITE sip packet on outbound leg showing the privacy=yes and that it we are sending the desired CallerID.

```
Remote-Party-ID: "11234567890" <sip:+11234567890@192.168.0.0>;party=calling;screen=yes;privacy=full
```

When the inbound callee is not restricted the outbound leg INVITE sip packet shows privacy=off as expected and displays the inbound called number.

```
Remote-Party-ID: "11234567890" <sip:+11234567890@198.168.0.0>;party=calling;screen=yes;privacy=off
```

What should I be doing to show the caller id in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You can update kazoo to latest 4.3 branch and latest monster-ui
Caller-ID privacy now managed from web interface.

In current kazoo this more simple then on kazoo 3.0.